# JavaScript Function with an un-named 'sub-function'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JavaScript but I'm having a little difficulty understanding a section of code:

```
// Download data
ajax({url: URL, type: 'json'},
  function(json) {
    // Data is supplied here

  },
  function(error) {
    console.log('Ajax failed: ' + error);
  }
);
```

You can see the code in context here: https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/js-apps/js-ajax/

After doing a bit of reading around JavaScript functions, I don't understand what the lines which look like this do:

```
function(error) {...
```

It looks like a 'sub-function', under the 'main function' called 'ajax', but far as I can see the function doesn't have a name. Shouldn't a function look like this instead?

```
function myFunction(p1, p2) {...
```

or (if I want to declare and use the function)

```
var function myFunction(p1, p2) {...
```

Can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: It is a callback function and executes as soon as something is done, you are passing this function into another function, why do you need a name for this?

Comment: This is actually callback mechanism. Some functions like ajax() above require callback functions to report success and failure of some operation. Such functions are normally written in inline fashion as above. When writing a function as inline then names are not provided. Furthermore, number of parameters defined depend on the main function that calls these inline functions. I hope this explanation is enough,

Comment: That makes great sense - Thanks Muhammad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a "callback" function. It doesn't have a name, because you can declare anonymous functions in JavaScript. Here's a trivial example of a function that allows a callback:

```
function awesome(callback) {
  console.log('hello');

  return callback();
}

awesome(function() {
  console.log('world');
});

// output: 'hello' 'world'
```

The real benefit of callbacks is that they can be used when things happen *asynchronously*, such as with AJAX functions. Here's an [interesting article from Rising Stack](https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/) regarding async functions and how they can be handled in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It is a function passed as an argument. The passed function will in this case be called when the ajax call succeeds, and the passed function needs to take the parameters (json) that the `ajax` function expects.

It could have a name (for clarity):

```
ajax(
    {url: URL, type: 'json'},
    function success(json) {
        // Data is supplied here
    },
    function failure(error) {
        console.log('Ajax failed: ' + error);
    }
);
```

It could also be defined separately (for reusability or clarity):

```
var success = function (json) {
    // Data is supplied here
};

var failure = function (error) {
    console.log('Ajax failed: ' + error);
};

ajax(
    {url: URL, type: 'json'},
    success,
    failure
);
```

Usually it will just be unnamed/anonymous by convention, but I have many times used a separately defined function to avoid code duplication - like when using the same error handling for multiple ajax calls.